# CSS position of divs without id

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is there a way to position or style `divs` without knowing the id?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #main div {
     background-color:coral;
     width: 40%;
    }
    #main div div  {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 60%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div >Red DIV</div>
    <div >Blue DIV</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to target elements is with ids or classes, but you can use [`:nth-child`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)

```css
#main > div {
  background-color:coral;
  width: 40%;

  float: left;
}
#main > div:nth-child(2)  {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 60%;
  
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div >Red DIV</div>
    <div >Blue DIV</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you one question if you like to Position first div left and second div right?

Comment: Thanks, so much i just test it and wok great, but in my code i run in to trouble because inside divs there are others divs as well i just need the first div to set the setting not the rest inside other div

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? i'm not quite sure what you are asking.

Comment: i have more Divs inside the main divs the Red and Blue div, this divs also are taking the nth-child(2) settings, and i only need the first DIV to take it

Comment: i gotcha. you need to do add `>`, see my update. that means direct descendant

Answer (score 0):

```css
#main div:nth-of-type(1) { background-color: red; }

#main div:nth-of-type(2) { background-color: blue; }
```